# Delimit Sentences in C++, after each period

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Sorry if I am brief I had a lot of trouble putting this code up here.
I want to basically parse the file "question.txt"
and every time I see a period i want a new line
basically:

> hey jim.(new line)
>
> hey tim.(newline)

```
int main(){

    ifstream openQuiz;
    openQuiz.open("questions.txt");
    string line;
    //int count = 0;
    //Check for errors 
    if (openQuiz.fail()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
    }

    //Reading from beginning to ending;
    while (!openQuiz.eof()) {

        
    
    }

    openQuiz.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Please do not add C tag for C++ questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  ifstream f("file.txt");
  char c;
  while (f.get(c)) {
    cout << c;
    if (c=='.') cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

How's this for you?
You can read more about `std::istream::get()` here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Comment: Thanks for the resource buddy! and I will quickly try this out and see if it is exactly what I neeed. Because all I am finding online is people talking about streams using "ss" which is way to confusing

Answer (score 1):

You could use an fstream instead of an ifstream. The difference is that fstreams can do input and output at the same time.
Then you could simply read the characters one by one. Whenever you read a '.' write a newline.